# How to execute code when switching views

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I have 2 views. They are both connected to separate controllers. I've attached a picture of how I'm transitioning to the next view [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW9Xa.png). The start view doesn't have any additional code, however the second view does. This is what I have:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

None of that code seems to execute when I switch from the first transition to the second. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting a non-`.zero` frame for your web view?

Comment: After editing your code to reflect calling `viewWillAppear` correctly (and was proposed by @GaryMatkin), I'm seeing *way* to many other things incorrectly coded - particularly an override of `loadView`, which doesn't exist! Are you *sure* you've posted code that builds?

Comment: @dfd Of course there is such method as `loadView` - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview

Comment: @Losiowaty i suppose you should never call loadView when we are using storyboards.... It should be used only when we are creating ViewController programmatically correct me if am wrong.

Comment: You shouldn’t call it directly, but no part of the code suggest that OP is doing that. He simply overrode it, and the system should call his implementation. I don’t see a problem with using it with a storyboard as long as you understand that it will basically discard whatever you have in storyboard. I’ve seen this used the way OP does, especially since you cannot add `WKWebView`, only `UIWebView` in storyboard.

Comment: Thanks @Losiowaty, I've never seen that override before. (Learned my something new today!) To the OP, reading that link on `loadView` I'm wondering if that's your issue. I'm not seeing code that suggests you are using IB - that would *not* be a case for using this override - but I create my VC through code too and could not glean *where* in the view lifecycle this executes. Have you tried using `viewDidLoad` instead?

Comment: @dfd Yes I tried using viewDidLoad, didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your `viewWillAppear` does not have the correct parameters. The hint is that you don't need the `override` keyword to get it to compile.

It should be:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    ...
}
```

Also, you are calling the wrong `super` function.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I made the changes that you described, and the code is still not being run.

Comment: @HuyVo You may be right. My next question was going to be “How do you know the code is not being run?” There’s a difference between code not running and not getting the results you are after.

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase, I click the button that I set up to transition views, and the 2nd views' code doesn't run at all. I added prints and it didn't print in the console.